# Angular & Webpack Dependency Versioning

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, require, dependency-management

Recently I've been running into an issue and I'm not sure how to best resolve it. We have a very modular architecture on the front end. We write individual angular components, put them in different repo's, and then include them in other apps as they are required, built with webpack & included via NPM.

Recently I've run into issues where multiple versions of a module end up in the compiled `/dist` folder coming from different places such as:

1. Directly included in the App I'm working on
2. 2x Indirectly included through a module that I included (see chart for details).

The reason different versions could be used is that at the time `CodeA` is written `ModuleA` may be at version 1, then at a later date `CodeB` is written which also uses `ModuleA` which is now at version 2.

Then `CodeA` and `CodeB` are included in `CodeC` and now you have a module name collision on `ModuleA`.

With this setup, I believe if the multiple modules by the same name are loaded, the last one to get loaded is going to be the code behind that module name. Meaning it will be the one to be used by all modules. So there's no guarantee that the most up-to-date version is will be used. This usually results in getting an error that a method on `ModuleA` by name XXX does not exist.

To make sure I'm running the latest version of the module I have to go in and manually update (`npm install`) and build with webpack (`npm run build`) each library and then push them all to Github. Then I have to `npm install` in my root app. This isn't always an easy thing to do as the individual libraries' code may need updated to use the latest version of the module in question.

I'm looking for a solution to this issue. I'm guessing a structural/organizational change that will help us to not get into this predicament. If you have any solutions/advice/articles I need to check out please share. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Your dependencies should be in package.json since u are using npm -- so npm will care about versions.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Currently we deal in `/dist/ code. So every dependency is compiled into a dist file with all of it's dependencies. Would you advise against that and always require() the src files that way you can use the current version of the node_modules.